# SQL group by year and show months of previous year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 columns in my table:

```
client manager year month value
```

and I would like to pivot it to the table where months should be in columns:

```
client manager year m01 m02 m03 m04 m05 m06 m07 m08 m09 m10 m11 m12
```

I know that I can do it in this way:

```
select
client, 
manager, 
year,
sum(case when month = 1 the value else 0 end) m01, 
sum(case when month = 2 the value else 0 end) m02, 
sum(case when month = 3 the value else 0 end) m03, 
sum(case when month = 4 the value else 0 end) m04, 
sum(case when month = 5 the value else 0 end) m05, 
sum(case when month = 6 the value else 0 end) m06, 
sum(case when month = 7 the value else 0 end) m07, 
sum(case when month = 8 the value else 0 end) m08, 
sum(case when month = 9 the value else 0 end) m09, 
sum(case when month = 10 the value else 0 end) m10,
sum(case when month = 11 the value else 0 end) m11, 
sum(case when month = 12 the value else 0 end) m12
from t
group by
client, 
manager, 
year
```

But for some additional calculations, I want to add m0 and m13 columns to my table, where m0 is month 12 of the previous year and m13 is month 1 of the next year.

Is there a simple way (without using joins, lead and lag functions) to do it with a simple group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate the rows which are the first (or last) month of the year and assign then a new month 13 (or 0) of the previous (or next) year; you can do this using the `DECODE` function or a `CASE` expression. Then you can pivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT client,
         manager,
         year,
         month,
         value
  FROM   t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT client,
         manager,
         DECODE( month, 1, year - 1, 12, year + 1 ),
         DECODE( month, 1,       13, 12,        0 ),
         value
  FROM   t
  WHERE  month IN ( 1, 12 )
)
PIVOT( SUM( value ) FOR month IN (
  0 AS m0,
  1 AS m1,
  2 AS m2,
  3 AS m3,
  4 AS m4,
  5 AS m5,
  6 AS m6,
  7 AS m7,
  8 AS m8,
  9 AS m9,
  10 AS m10,
  11 AS m11,
  12 AS m12,
  13 AS m13
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is certainly possible, there is not a "simple" way because one row in the original data needs to be in multiple rows in the result set.

That said, this seems quite simple:

```
with t as (
      < your query here >
     )
select t.*,
       lag(m12) over (partition by client, manager order by year) as m0,
       lead(m1) over (partition by client, manager order by year) as m13
from t;
```

Comment: I would like not to use lag and lead because there are 500 millions of rows in my source table. But if there is no "simple" way, this is the answer.

Comment: @Room'on . . . You are doing an aggregation on 500 million rows and worried about `lag()` after the aggregation???  You need to learn more about query performance.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, yes, I need =)

Answer (score 1):

You can make union (or join) with JAN and DEC data copied to other years, but I doubt it would be faster than `lead` and `lag`:

```
select * 
  from (
    select client, manager, value, year, month from t 
    union all
    select client, manager, value, 
           case month when  1 then year - 1 
                      when 12 then year + 1 end, 
           case month when  1 then 13 
                      when 12 then  0 end
      from t where month in (1, 12))
  pivot (sum(value) for month in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))
  order by client, manager, year
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b21be5812e9be2eb2926222cb416499)</sup>**